# Best way to query contents of CompositionLocal in a Jetpack Compose unit test?

Tags: android, unit-testing, automated-tests, android-jetpack-compose

Assume I have some top-level static CompositionLocal used throughout the app:

```
val LocalConfig = staticCompositionLocalOf<Config> { error("no config") }
@Composable fun App() { 
   CompositionLocalProvider(LocalConfig provides Config(...,...,...)) {
        app()
    }
}
```

What is the best way to then query the contents of the `Config` instance in a Compose unit test?

```
class BasicTest {

    @get:Rule
    val composeTestRule = createComposeRule()

    @Test
    fun myTest(): Unit = with(composeTestRule) {
        setContent { App() }
        // do stuff
        val config : Config = /* something */
        assertEquals(config.foo(), "foo")
    }
}
```

I'm trying to avoid assigning the supposed `Config` instance to a global variable and then using that.